# Python TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'master'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to build a GUI in Python at the moment, and I'm stuck at this part in particular. Every time I try to run my code it just throws the error `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'master'`. I can't seem to find where I'm passing  it more than one value, and it's got me scratching my head. I tried searching the error but the fixes other people had listed I can't see how to make them work with this one. Any guidance would be much appreciated. See code sample below:

```
class Plotter(tk.Canvas):
    """Creates a canvas for use in a GUI
    Plotter() -> Canvas
    """
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, master = master, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()
        self.bg = 'white'
        self.relief = 'raised'

class AnimalDataPlotApp(object):
    """This is the top level class for the GUI, and is hence responsible for
    creating and maintaining instances of the above glasses
    """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """Initialises the window and creates the base window for the GUI.
        __init__() -> None
        """
        master.title('Animal Data Plot App')
        self._master = master
        self._text = tk.Text(master)
        self._text.pack
        menubar = tk.Menu(master)
        master.config(menu = menubar)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar) #puts filemenu into the menubar
        menubar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label = 'Open', command = self.open_file)

        #frame for canvas
        plotter_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg = 'red')
        plotter_frame.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, anchor = tk.NW, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        #frame for buttons
        button_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg = 'yellow')
        button_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.NW, ipadx=50, fill = tk.X)

        #Label on the top left
        left_label = tk.Label(button_frame, text='Animal Data Sets', bg='orange')
        left_label.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.X)

        #second frame, for selection list
        selection_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg = 'blue')
        selection_frame.pack(side = tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.NW, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        #draw buttons in frame
        select = tk.Button(button_frame, text ='Select')
        select.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.N)
        deselect = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Deselect')
        deselect.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.N)

        self.selectionbox = SelectionBox(selection_frame)
        self.selectionbox.pack(side = tk.TOP, expand = True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        #self._selectionbox.show_animals(self._data)

        self.plotter = Plotter(plotter_frame)
        self.plotter.pack(side = tk.TOP, expand = True, fill=tk.BOTH)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
super().__init__(self, master = master, **kwargs)
```

If you're using `super()`, you don't need to specify `self` explicitly.

You are getting that error because `self` is being interpreted as the argument for `master`. So it's like if you were calling `__init__(master=self, master=master, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is in the following line in `Plotter.__init__()` -

```
super().__init__(self, master = master, **kwargs)
```

When calling the parent's `__init__` method, you do not need to pass the `self` argument, when you do that, it is getting treated as the `master` argument for the parent, and then when you try to pass `master` as `master=master` , it causes your error.

You should simply do -

```
super().__init__(master = master, **kwargs)
```