# handling kwargs in POST and CBV

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937827/using-a-queryset-to-generate-options-for-select-widget-on-integerfield-in-django/52940744#52940744), I had trouble displaying imported choices in a select widget because I was missing a (should have been) obvious bit of code.  Now, my GET (seems to) work just fine.  The problem is I am doing something wrong in my POST.

What I can't figure out is how the kwargs should be handled in POST.  If I  include kwargs in my post method in the line

```
form = Enter_SW_Room(request.POST, **kwargs)
```

I receive the error `__init__() got multiple values for argument 'data'`.  Looking around stack overflow, I find most of the problems with this error stem from calling self in super (or other calling errors).  E.g. this [problem / solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153404/python-typeerror-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-master).  If I try to work around this problem by NOT passing kwargs, the validation fails.  (I think because there is now a value for the appropriate field, but the choices are gone.)

So, what I figure is that either I'm doing something simple but importantly wrong again, or I need to modify the form validation.  (or ???)

Here's all the code (snipped for brevity):

```
''' views.py '''
class DockingBay(FormMixin, TemplateView):
    form_class = Enter_SW_Room

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        # snip; create my_avatar_choices, which is more than just a queryset
        kwargs['avatar_list'] = my_avatars_choices
        return kwargs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        # snip
        my_rooms_list = []  # used in the template
        form = Enter_SW_Room(**kwargs)
        args = {'form': form, 'my_rooms_list': my_rooms_list}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        kwargs = self.get_form_kwargs()
        form = Enter_SW_Room(request.POST, **kwargs)
        if form.is_valid():
            # snip - logic to enter the room with correct passcode
            return redirect('swdice:swroom', swroom_id)
        else:
            # snip - error handling will go here


'''forms.py'''
class Enter_SW_Room(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EnterSWroom
        widgets = {'default_avatar': forms.Select()}
        fields = ('room_number', 'passcode', 'default_avatar')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        imported_list = kwargs.pop('avatar_list')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['default_avatar'].choices = imported_list

    default_avatar = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])


'''template'''
<h4>Enter a room using passcode</h4>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <col width="240">
            <col width="120">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Room ID:</strong>
                <br>This will be a number.</td>
                <td>{{form.room_number}} <br>
                    <strong>{{ form.room_number.errors }}</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Passcode:</strong>
                <br>If the room is open, or you have been in it before, leave this  blank.</td>
                <td>{{form.passcode}} <br>
                    <strong>{{ form.passcode.errors }}</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Avatar:</strong>
                <br>Select your avatar.</td>
                <td>{{form.default_avatar}} <br>
                    <strong>{{ form.default_avatar.errors }}</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Enter Room</button>
    </form>
    <hr>
```

Comment: As an aside, you should try to avoid overriding `get()` or `post()` for Django class based views. You can end up duplicating code or missing out on functionality. I would try to use `FormView`, and override `form_valid` and `form_invalid` if you want extra code there.

Comment: Thank you; I will read up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the error by changing the code to:

```
form = Enter_SW_Room(**kwargs)
```

Your current code is equivalent to

```
form = Enter_SW_Room(data=request.POST, **kwargs)
```

Since `kwargs` already contains `'data'`, you get the multiple argument error.

Comment: Oy!  Simple, but important.  Thanks!